# MS Access export error: “Reserved error (-1); there is no message for this error.”

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to a export a `Select` query from an Access database I was given as a pipe-delimited text file. It used to work, but then the client had me change the query.

I did that and now I get the error:

> Reserved error (-1); there is no message for this error.

when I try to export, so the export fails.

I've never encountered this error before and can't find anything about it online.

Comment: What did you change between the two queries?

Comment: And what process are you using to export the file?  Are you using VBA code, a macro, saved export options in Access?

Comment: It originally was an inner join and it was changed to a left join. I'm using saved export options in Access. I right-click on the saved Select query, click Export, choose Text File, and then go through the Wizard.

Comment: I assume that change would at most produce some extra rows with null values. But I'm confused now... you said "saved export", but then described redefining the export criteria and the wizard. A "saved export" skips the wizard because all parameters of the export have been saved. Moving on, does the new query run successfully alone? How many total records?  Can the query be exported in another format, say Excel?

Comment: My mistake. When you said "saved export", I thought you meant exporting from a saved query. The query does run successfully and I can also query it to get the number of records, which is over 22 million. Excel doesn't work then but I've tried comma and tab delimited text as well as csv. They don't work either, returning the same error.

Comment: I was able to figure it out and posted my answer below. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. The text file I was trying to export would be over 4GB. I removed some fields that aren't needed or that I can add later, which put it under 4GB, so it successfully exported.