# Access 2016 reserved error -1 when exporting as text

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to export a query table that is quite large (not sure how many lines, but likely millions) from Access 2016. I followed these steps:

1. right click on query
2. export > text file
3. I did not check export data with formatting and layout (I'm told you shouldn't use that with large amount of data)
4. I tried to export it as delimited and as fixed width.

When exporting it gives me the following error:

> "Reserved error (-1); there is no message for this error."

I exported other tables before using the same method and I never got this error. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639623/ms-access-export-error-reserved-error-1-there-is-no-message-for-this-error) post it could be that the data it is trying to export is too large, but in my case I can't remove any fields..

The query I used to create the table is:

```
SELECT Final_parsed_userlogs_access_longuri.ip, Large_categories.big_cat
FROM (All_categories_from_all_unique_uri INNER JOIN Final_parsed_userlogs_access_longuri ON All_categories_from_all_unique_uri.uri = Final_parsed_userlogs_access_longuri.uri) INNER JOIN Large_categories ON All_categories_from_all_unique_uri.small_cat = Large_categories.small_cat;
```

When I run this query within Access 2016 it instantly runs and has no problems.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

P.S. If you need any other examples of my data just say so and I'll get it for you :)

Comment: Hummm.... It reminds me old versions of Windows where it was quite common to the an error message reading **Illegal Error**. No idea man.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 so that's kind of old. Could that be the problem then? Access 2016 says it can be used on Windows 7 so that would be weird.

Comment: What is the current size of your database file? Access tends to use temporary objects with migration purposes and you may be exceeding its [limitations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c).

Comment: The database file is about 1.8GB. Is that too large then? I don't think I can remove any tables out of the database file though.

Comment: Do a test by applying filter criteria to reduce the dataset size. Start with 1 record export and expand from there. When does it fail? Access has a 2GB size limit. When was the last time you ran Compact & Repair?